# Ranger File Manager as Default File Manager Errors

Tags: xfce, file-manager, ranger

I could not get Ranger to be my default file manager using every tutorial I could find. Help is appreciated - I'll describe my attempts below:

1. In Default Application -> Utilities -> Other... -> EITHER `ranger "%s"` OR `xfce4-terminal -x ranger "%s"`

- Click Open Desktop Folder Icon Result: *Failed to execute default File Manager. Input/output error.*

2. In Default Application -> Utilities -> Other... `xfce4-terminal -T ranger -x /home/user/.scripts/Ranger_Default_File_Manager.sh "%s"`

2.1 Ranger_Default_File_Manger.sh is just `ranger $@` AND `zsh`

- Click Open Desktop Folder Icon Result: *Inaccessible paths: home/user/Desktop/Folder*

  - The `/` before `home` is missing for some reason? So I tried adding a slash to `ranger /$@`

    - Click Open Desktop Folder Icon Result: *Inaccessible paths: /file:///home/ertecturing/Desktop/Folder*

      - The problem is that `file:///` should be `file:////` (4 slashes), I've tested manually it with 4 slashes & it works, but don't know how to automate it to have 4 slashes.

3. In Default Application -> Utilities -> Other... -> ranger.desktop
   3.1 Desktop File Configuration: `Terminal=false` AND `Exec=xfce4-terminal -x ranger %F`

- Click Open Desktop Folder Icon Result: *Failed to execute default File Manager. Input/output error.*

NOTE: I can get Ranger to work as file/folder opener by right-clicking a desktop file/folder and selecting open with ranger, but I don't want to have to right-click an icon & pick ranger every time.

Also Shared: [Xfce Forums](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=65125#p65125) & [r/Ranger](https://www.reddit.com/r/ranger/comments/rbjd8t/ranger_file_manager_as_default_file_manager_errors/)

Comment: How can you tell which FM is the default? There is usually nothing to automatically open a FM. I don't know. I've never even thought about the concept of having a default file manager. Are you sure you need that?

Comment: @Brian For Xfce I go to Default Applications -> Utilities tab -> File Manager (drop down list with "Other..." option you can type in). This is useful for when I want to click a desktop folder icon & automatically have it open in Ranger, or if my browser says "Open In Folder" for a downloaded file it'll open in Ranger instead of a gui like Thunar or Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282286/how-to-set-ranger-as-default-file-manager

Additional Solution for Spaces:

1. `OUT=$(echo "$@" | sed "s:///:////:g" | sed "s/%20/ /g")`
2. `xfce4-terminal -T "Ranger File Manager" -x ranger "$OUT"`